# Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

when starting the application, see the below error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blockDataController': Injection of resource dependencies failed;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blockSummaryImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'prodCodeMapper' defined in file [D:\YueNiuProject\StockMarket\yueniu-stock-data\market-data-dao\target\classes\com\yueniu\stock\market\data\mapper\block\ProdCodeMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception;
    nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Comment: please share your application.properties and pom file..

Comment: You need to make sure the JDBC driver for the database you are using is included in the classpath when you run your application, and make sure that the database connection URL is correct.

Comment: please use code format when you send code or logs

Answer (score 13):

the connection with a sql database, you must configure datasource in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://..
spring.datasource.username=//..
spring.datasource.password=//..
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont need to config the datasource, you can use the `exclude` . like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

it would not register the DataSource with default configuration, then passed the issue for throw Exception

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you also have an `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation, you may need to specify the `exclude` there instead, as that seems to override the `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if you bean configuration in same package it won't work. Like the properties loading bean need to be in separate package. Not sure this answer will be accepted or not , for me it worked after moving below code into different package.

```
    @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(oracleEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```